# ‘Correct’ way of writing a function?

Tags: typography, best-practices

So for all these years, I have been writing a function `f(x)` as `$\mathop{f}(x)$`.

But now that I begin to think about a correct way of writing a function, what should it be?

Is it `f(x)` or `\mathop{f}(x)` or `\mathop{f}\left(x\right)` or `f\left(x\right)`?

Or is it actually none of these?

Comment: There is no "right" way but most common way. Usually I do `$f(x)=$` to define and then refer to it as `$f$`. But sometimes, depending on the size of arguments, I do `$f \bigl(   \bigr)$`.

Comment: I simply use `f(x)` and consider all the other proposed usages wrong.

Comment: `\mathop{f}(x)` is absolutely wrong because the leter `f` is vertically positioned not by baseline but centered by math axis. Try `\mathop{g}(x)` where the wrong result is more visible. Of course, the vertically positioning by math axis can be cancelled by adding something second to the `\mathop`parameter (`\kern0pt` in egreg's example) but normal `f(x)` is the best.

Answer (score 6):

I simply use `f(x)` (inside a formula, that is, between `$...$` or `\[...\]` or any other mathematical construct, which shall be implicit in what follows) and consider all the other proposed usages wrong. One might argue about `\mathop{\kern0pt f}(x)` so a thin space would be added in front of the `f` if preceded by certain kinds of atoms (what happens for `\sin` and `\log`). A definition should be

```
\newcommand{\fn}[1]{\mathop{\kern0pt #1}\nolimits}
```

and `\fn{f}(x)` would give the desired result.

However, the following example shows that it is suboptimal: there is no reason for the thin space.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\fn}[1]{\mathop{\kern0pt #1}\nolimits}

\begin{document}

$g(x)f(x)$

$\fn{g}(x)\fn{f}(x)$

$f(x)\ne f'(x)$

$\fn{f}(x)\ne \fn{f}'(x)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but you're not using `f(x)`, you're using `$f(x)$`. Maybe that's given to a mathematician, but I thought you were in fact writing `f(x)` until I saw your code.

Comment: @Sverre I use `f(x)` inside a formula; that's implicit. But I'll add it for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

If your typoscript is to be processed (not retyped) by a scientific journal or book publisher, then stick to conventions and keep it as simple as possible lest you will annoy the copy editor. Hence `f(x)`. Or `f\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)` if the function argument has extra height or depth.

If you are your own editor, then, as others have said, there is no such category as "correctness". Still: why not keep things simple?